# Стоит ли мне использовать WeakMap вместо Map, где это возможно?

Tags: javascript

Я обрабатываю в своих JS приложениях данные немалых объемов(к примеру - json файл с массивом объектов суммарно размером 10+ мегабайт) и во время итерации по, к примеру, массиву использую `Map` вместо объектов, для получения данных по ключу, что помогает мне ускорить код в несколько раз.

И сейчас я для исправления проблем с утечками памяти пару раз использовал `WeakMap` и задался вопросом:

Если я работаю с данными таких объемов, то стоит ли мне практически всегда отдавать предпочтение `WeakMap` и вообще имеет ли смысл использовать `Map` при разработке, учитывая то, что они могут неожиданно вызвать утечку оперативной памяти?

Comment: Ваши слова: _для итерирования по этим данным использую Map_. А как Вы планируете итерировать по WeakMap?

Comment: можно один минимизированный пример где ты map сменил на weakmap

Comment: Извиняюсь, что неясно выяснился. Имел ввиду "для получения значения из этих данных во время итерации по, например, массиву".

Comment: При условии что `array` - массив объектов -> `array.forEach(item => /*операции с myWeakMap.get(item)*/ )`, к примеру

Comment: Armen, я использовал библиотеку для поиска, которая принимала параметры и массив объектов(`index = new searchLib({/*params*/}`) и для добавления данных - `index.add(myArray)`). После создания первого экземпляра все было хорошо, но так как мне необходимо обновлять данные каждые 20 минут, мне необходимо было удалять старый экземпляр и создавать новый, но так как перед добавлением данных в `myArr` я обрабатывал каждый объект с данными(которые лежат в `Map`) у меня(как я понял) оставались ссылки на старые Map и GC не очищал память после удаления `index`(что каждые 20 минут добавляло 10мб озу)

Comment: После небольшого изменения структуры данных на объекты и изменением Map на WeakMap GC начал все неиспользуемые данные очищать.

Comment: Пример кода будет > 50 строк, так что я описал текстом, чтобы было удобнее, если не против

Comment: @Mark у меня вазможно знаний поменше будет но по данному примеру я  не магу понять если данные уже в каком то массиве то зачем не брать их оттуда а искать в map который нужно еше и заполнять данными ? ключи обекты?  если же нужно удалять данные то лутше делать руками чем палагатся на weekmap он описан так что если нет ссылок GC как может удалить так и может не удалить то есть по прихоти. Это мае мнение возможно более опытные люди дадут другой ответ. Извиняюсь мои нынишние знания не могут дать точный ответ

Comment: Задача усложняется, когда появляется необходимость объединить все объекты, находящиеся в нескольких массивах объектов, по одному одинаковому свойству(например `id`). Например это может быть необходимо для удаления повторяемых свойств или просто для группировки всех необходимых данных. Лучше сразу конвертировать все объекты в `Map` и ставить ключом повторяющееся свойство. Таким образом можно буквально в несколько сотен миллисекунд пройтись по всем объектам, в то время как доступ по обычному объекту может затребовать секунды(в моем случае 1950мс, а реализация на `Map` - 150мс)

Comment: Но если данные, которые лежат в `Map` после обработки положить в массив, а массив использовать в каком либо классе(пример про библиотеку выше), то память может не очистится, даже если вручную очистить Map используя `Map.clear` и очистив используемый массив. Вот тут мне и помог WeakMap, который автоматически очистился после очистки массива/Мапы

Comment: Все ваши комментарии сводятся к одному - без конкретного примера кода с использованием Map, WeakMap никто вам ответить точно не сможет. WeakMap  - не серебрянная пуля и везде его использовать не надо. А надо использовать там, где надо. А где надо, надо определять по конкретному коду\алгоритму\ситуации.

Comment: Вот я и заинтересован - где можно почитать о том, в каких случаях `WeakMap`, например, имеет сильно хуже производительность чем `Map`? Если же производительность одинакова и нужно обрабатывать только элементы `WeakMap`(а не саму `WeakMap` с `forEach`, например) , то мне кажется, что можно начать привыкать к ней, вместо `Map`, чтобы не была неожиданно получена утечка памяти, которую понадобится искать.

Comment: Весь интернет только и заполнен информацией, что "WeakMap = Map, но чуть более ограниченная и у неё чистится память правильно" с несколькими узкоспециализированными примерами, которые отлично решают свои проблемы, но **почему же её стоит использовать только в таких случаях**, а не наоборот использовать `Map` только для специальных ситуаций? (не учитывая то, что необходимо для этого немного усложнить код)